# How to get back to default screen size in kivy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Unfortunately I used the following:

```
Config.set('graphics','width',850)
Config.set('graphics','height',850)
Config.write()
```

in my  of kivy file. My kivy application's window(screen) is opening in 'ipad' screen size(denoted in Screen module).  From that instance in 'config.ini' system added '[module] screen = ipad'. Help me get through this and how to restore my screen size to normal?

Answer (score 2):

1. The default settings for height and width is as follow. Edit the config file located in `~/.kivy/config.ini`.

   ```
   [graphics]
   height = 600
   width = 800
   ```
2. In your kivy app, either remove / comment off the `write` statement, or write the new config into your app directory.

Comment: Hi, @ikolim , you just save my day. From some days ago, each window, even I run 'hello world!', the window size is about 600x300, and the resizable was disabled. Like it was specified by God. I just find this post, and goto config.ini. Now things are fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The default values for height and width is (600, 800)

To rest you can either do

1. Rerun `Configer.set` with default values.

```
 Config.set('graphics','width',800)
 Config.set('graphics','height',600)
 Config.write()
```

2. Or manual edit the config file

```
[graphics]
height = 600
width = 800
```

3. Or you can just remove the `config.ini`. On the next run it will automatically be created with default values

The config file will be here:

- Windows: `C:\Users\<UserName>\.kivy\config.ini`
- Linus: `/home/<UserName>/.kivy/config.ini`
- macOS: `/Users/<UserName>/.kivy/config.ini`

Reference: [kivy doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/config.html)